# Will mail service affect? If I change hosting provider

Tags: email, hosting

I have registered my site with one service provider and I am using another service provider for hosting (by the way of changing name server), I configured and using many emails from existing hosting service provider.

Now I would like to shift my site content to another service provider. Here I would like to clear my doubt after change to new service provider may I keep mail with old service provider or have I to configure again?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you change the Nameserver of your domain then all services will be effected like MX records, A records etc. Here, I would suggest you to that only change the A record of your website to that ip address where you wanted to host the website from the Domain control panel.